# Mayavi hangs under Jupyter QtConsole

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, jupyter, mayavi

After installing Mayavi from [Christoph Gohlke's  Python builds for Windows site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), the following works from a plain interactive Python prompt:

```
import mayavi.mlab as MM
MM.test_surf()
```

But when I ran the same under `jupyter-qtconsole`, the window comes up and hangs.

---

For reference, I have the following packages, installed in the order given, from the above website, over a fresh Python 2.7.13 install.

(These are just the dependencies to get a working environment with Jupyter, SciPy, matplotlib, Mayavi and just a couple of useful extras.)

- numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- MS VS 2008 redistributable (from MS website)
- Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- traits-4.6.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
- VTK-5.10.1+qt486-cp27-none-win32.whl
- mayavi-4.3.1+vtk510-cp27-none-win32.whl
- pyzmq-15.4.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- certifi-2016.8.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
- tornado-4.4.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- MarkupSafe-0.23-cp27-none-win32.whl
- Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- mistune-0.7.3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- pytz-2016.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- pyparsing-2.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- Pillow-3.3.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- wxPython_common-3.0.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
- wxPython-3.0.2.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
- python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- PySide-1.2.2-cp27-none-win32.whl
- matplotlib-2.0.0b3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- scandir-1.5-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- ipython-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- ipykernel-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- ipyparallel-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- ipywidgets-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- Bottleneck-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- numexpr-2.6.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- pandas-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- sympy-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this thread](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2012-February/009516.html). This works from within Jupyter QTconsole:

```
import mayavi.mlab as MM
%gui qt
MM.test_surf()
```

Note that the `%gui qt` command has to be issued **after** importing Mayavi.

(The explanation is that it "initialises Qt event loop support", not that this makes much sense to me.)